# Importing public files - Drupal upgrade from 7 to 9

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-9

I am trying to upgrade Drupal from 7 to 9.

When I run the following command to import the public files from D7 site to D9 site:

`drush migrate-import upgrade_d7_file`

Output is

`upgrade_d7_file Migration - 1129 failed.`

Then I ran

`drush mmsg upgrade_d7_file`

It says,

`upgrade_d7_file:uri: File '//sitesdefault/files//images/test1.jpg' does not exist`

Public file system path in source site is

`sites/default/files/`

Not sure why it's removing the front slash from sites/default and added to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It works now.

I had to add `--legacy-root=http://domainname` to the `drush migrate-upgrade` command.